# Water heater coding problem

Tags: arduino-uno

I need help with my coding. I'm still learning on how to use interval `millis()`.

Currently I'm working on a water heater with a safety feature. This means that you can only pour water out when you activate the child-lock feature. The child-lock feature will turn on for 5 seconds and within that 5 seconds if you pour the water out, the timer will pause until you finish pouring your water and the 5 second timer will start again and the system goes off after that.

If the child lock feature on for 5 second without any action, it will turn off the system again. My lecturer does not allow me to use the `delay()` function so I already did my coding using `millis()`.

This is my code so far:

```
const int redLed = 2;
const int greenLed = 3;
const int yellowLed = 4;
const int greenbigLed = 7;

const int buttonPin1 = 5;
const int buttonPin2 = 6;

int buttonState1 = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;
float tempC ;
int analogPin = A0;
int yellowLedState = 0;

const long interval1 =0;
const long interval2 = 5000;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;   

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
pinMode(5,INPUT);
pinMode(6,INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
digitalWrite(yellowLed,yellowLedState);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int analogValue = analogRead(analogPin);
int buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
int buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
int yellowLedState = digitalRead(yellowLed);
tempC = analogValue / 10 ;
Serial.println(tempC);
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
unsigned long currentMillis2 = millis();

if (tempC <= 89.9 && tempC >= 0){
  digitalWrite(redLed,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(greenLed,LOW);
}else if(tempC == 102){
  digitalWrite(redLed,LOW);
  digitalWrite(greenLed,HIGH);
}

if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval2){
  previousMillis = currentMillis;
  if(buttonState1 == HIGH){
   // if(currentMillis2 - previousMillis2 >=interval2){
     if (yellowLedState == LOW) {
          yellowLedState = HIGH;
} 
digitalWrite(yellowLed, yellowLedState);
  } else{
  digitalWrite(yellowLed,LOW);
    }
}


if (buttonState2 == HIGH && yellowLedState == HIGH){
  digitalWrite(greenbigLed, HIGH);
}else{
  digitalWrite(greenbigLed,LOW);
}

}
```

Now, I'm able to pour out water when child lock feature activated, but the problem is the timer (interval) still ticking.

Is there any solution on how can I pause the interval whenever I'm pouring water (button2) and the interval starts back 5 sec when I release button2 (pouring water)?

I would glad if someone can help me. Ask me anything about my code.

Comment: Something else to think about in your code: What would happen if somehow the temperature got above 102? Wouldn't you want the heater to shut off in that case? And do you really want the heater to not go on if the water is frozen?

Comment: Well in this case I am using potentiometer to appear as my tempC by dividing the reading by 10. Its kinda hard to use LM35 in class, so using potentiometer would give all the temperature I want easily.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Arjan for reminding me. I would love to contribute to the community. So this is my final coding and its worked for me :

```
const int redLed = 2;
const int greenLed = 3;
const int yellowLed = 4;
const int greenbigLed = 7;

const int buttonPin1 = 5;
const int buttonPin2 = 6;

int buttonState1 = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;
float tempC ;
int analogPin = A0;
int yellowLedState = 0;

const long interval = 5000;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;   


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
pinMode(5,INPUT);
pinMode(6,INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
digitalWrite(yellowLed,yellowLedState);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int analogValue = analogRead(analogPin);
int buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
int buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
int yellowLedState = digitalRead(yellowLed);
tempC = analogValue / 10 ;
Serial.println(tempC);
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

if (tempC <= 89.9 && tempC >= 0){
  digitalWrite(redLed,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(greenLed,LOW);
}else if(tempC == 102){
  digitalWrite(redLed,LOW);
  digitalWrite(greenLed,HIGH);
}

if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval){
  previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if(buttonState1 == HIGH){
         if (yellowLedState == LOW) {
              yellowLedState = HIGH;
    } 
    digitalWrite(yellowLed, yellowLedState);
  } else{
      digitalWrite(yellowLed,LOW);
    }
}


if (buttonState2 == HIGH && yellowLedState == HIGH){
  digitalWrite(greenbigLed, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(yellowLed,HIGH);
}else{
  digitalWrite(greenbigLed,LOW);
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval){
  previousMillis = currentMillis;
      if(buttonState1 == HIGH){
         if (yellowLedState == LOW) {
              yellowLedState = HIGH;
    } 
    digitalWrite(yellowLed, yellowLedState);
  } else{
      digitalWrite(yellowLed,LOW);
    }
}
}
}
```